# Display message for few moments before next action

Tags: java, jsf, message

In JSF page I would like to display a message for a few seconds and then proceed with next action. e.g. If a record gets deleted, I would like to display "Item Deleted" for 10 seconds and then message disappears and user proceed with next action.

How can I do this?

My JSF version is 1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript timer like this:

buttonToNextAction - could either be a button or a link depends on your needs.

```
function showMessage(){

document.getElementById('msg_id').style.display = "inline";

setTimeout ( "misAndClick()", 10000);
}

function misAndClick(){
document.getElementById('msg_id').style.display = "hidden";
document.getElementById('buttonToNextAction').click();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think JavaScript method is the only elegant method..